# Swift Linechart for timeline

Tags: swift, xcode, charts, swift3, cocoapods

I am planning to do a linechart, which should represent price changes based on a week, a month and so on. Therefore, I use the cocoapod "Charts" (github.com/danielgindi/Charts).

I always have the price changes for a certain point in time. I am wondering now how I could create the chart, that the x-line is showing the values according to the accurate time - and not the same distance for each value, even when two values are on the same day, and the next one 3 days after.

At the moment, it looks like this:
[image]

This should then help to insert a marker, where the user can move through the days/months, and see what the price was for each point in time.

Does anybody of you has an idea? I thought about adding values for each half hour to the dataset, with dummy values, to receive the same result, but this doesn't seem like a perfect solution..

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: how are you getting the data ? Though a REST API.

Comment: Yes, exactly, i get a json file, which includes all prices, and then i first filter for price type and price period - and then I want to show that as a line chart.

Comment: the best way is to use https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts for making line chart, it handles every solution to your question . I have recently used it

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing - added this info now to the main text. It is a great tool - just wondering how to get it showing the accurate timeline. Thanks already for your help!

Comment: What is the issue your are facing. explain

Comment: I added the picture. At the moment, the x-line contains just integer values for each price - but this should be the timeline..

Comment: you want that the time  should be displayed on the x axis then that depends on the data which you are receiving for the time line..
In linechart the x axis can only take string values

Comment: The big question is, is there a way to have a timeline without creating an array of data for each second or minute in the timeline, and just defining the time and values when it changed

Comment: No u have to set an array for data to be set on x axis